# How to create custom list field in serializer, which contains another serializer(model), django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I need to use a list of one model serializer in another, I have tried use `SerializerMethodField()` but didn't succeed.
 So i have following codes:

> models.py

```
class TyresGroup(models.Model):
    code  = models.CharField("Наименование группы колес", max_length=50)
    brand = models.CharField("Бренд", max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name        = "Группа колёс"
        verbose_name_plural = "Группы колёс"

def get_image_filename(instance, filename):
    code = instance.tyres_group.code
    slug = slugify(code)
    return "post_images/%s-%s" % (slug, filename)


class Images(models.Model):
    tyres_group = models.ForeignKey(TyresGroup, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image       = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename, verbose_name='Image')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name        = "Фотография"
        verbose_name_plural = "Фотографии"


class Tyre(models.Model):
    group        = models.ForeignKey(TyresGroup, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images       = models.ManyToManyField(Images, related_name='tyresgroup', blank=True)
    type         = models.CharField("Тип колеса", max_length=2, choices=TYRE_TYPES)
    code         = models.CharField("Код протектора", max_length=10)
    title        = models.CharField("Название", max_length=30)
    width        = models.CharField('Ширина', max_length=5, choices=WIDTH)
    height       = models.CharField('Высота', max_length=5, choices=HEIGHT)
    radius       = models.CharField('Радиус', max_length=5, choices=RADIUS)
    speed_index  = models.IntegerField('Индекс скорости')
    tread_depth  = models.IntegerField('Глубина протектора')
    standard     = models.FloatField('Какой-то стандарт')
    oa_dia       = models.IntegerField("OA DIA")
    max_pressure = models.IntegerField('Максимальное давление(КРА/PSI)')
    certificate  = models.CharField('Сертификат качества', max_length=5)
    distance     = models.IntegerField("Преодолимая дистанция колёс")
    max_loading  = models.IntegerField("Максимальная нагрузка")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name        = "Колесо"
        verbose_name_plural = "Колёса"
```

> and serializers.py:

```
class TyreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = ImagesSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Tyre
        fields = '__all__'


class TyresGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # tyres = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    # def get_tyres(self, instance):
    #     queryset = Tyre.objects.all()
    #     return queryset

    class Meta:
        model = TyresGroup
        fields = ['id', 'code', 'brand'] #, 'tyres']
```

> What i want to get:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "group": "VH200",
        "brand": "Aventus",
        "tyres": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "group": 1,
                "images": [...],
                "type": "Л",
                ...etc
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "group": 1,
                "images": [...],
                "type": "Л",
                ...etc
            }
        ]
    },
    ...etc
]
```

> What i have now:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "group": "VH200",
        "brand": "Aventus"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "group": "VH201",
        "brand": "Columbus"
    }
    ...etc
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your `TyresGroupSerializer` as below...

```
class TyresGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tyres = TyreSerializer(source='get_tyres', many=True)

    def get_tyres(self, instance):
        queryset = Tyre.objects.filter(group=instance)
        return queryset

    class Meta:
        model = TyresGroup
        fields = ['id', 'code', 'brand', 'tyres']
```

Comment: got such an error
```TypeError at /api/groups/

Object of type Tyre is not JSON serializable```

Comment: You have to create `serializer class` for `Tyre` also.

Comment: i have, mentioned above

Comment: You are calling `/api/groups/` and in `TyreGroup` model there are no any foreign key of `Tyre` so, it will not get `Tyre` object.

Comment: But mine architechture is made so as it's not possible to shift ```Tyre```, which is connected with ```Images``` and ```TyresGroup```, model above ```TyresGroup``` which is

Comment: I have updated my code, please check it and is it will throw any error just paste it here. I will help you to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SerializerMethodField() field in TyresGroupSerializer as follow.

```
class TyresSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = ImagesSerializer(many=True)
    tyregroups = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True) # If you do not want to write data of Tyre object otherwise you can set it to False

    def get_tyregroups(self, instance):
        serializer_class = TyreGroupSerializer(instance.group, many=True)
        serialized_data = serializer_class.data
        return serialized_data

    class Meta:
        model = Tyres
        fields = ['id', 'group', 'images', 'type', 'tyregroups'] # add all other fields which you want to in json

class TyresGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TyresGroup
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Got: 
```NameError at /api/groups/
name 'obj' is not defined```
After change of 'instance' with 'obj' got:
 ```AttributeError at /api/groups/
'TyresGroup' object has no attribute 'Tyre'```

Comment: okay, I think you need to take SerializerMethodField() in TyreSerializer(). I will update the answer try that.

Comment: @AbubakrAbduvakhidov just updated answer try this and call TyreSerializer through your api.

Comment: got an error ```AttributeError at /api/tyres/
'Tyre' object has no attribute 'Tyre'```

Comment: I just updated the answer. Please try with this one.